# Template argument deduction / variable template: how can I make it work?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a problem in wrapping a template class in a non-template one;

I'm trying to make this code work:

my_class.hpp

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_HPP
#define MY_CLASS_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class VectorPrinter {

private:

  template<class value_type>
  static std::vector<value_type> vec;

public:

  template<class value_type>
  VectorPrinter(const std::vector<value_type>& vec_)
  {
    vec = vec_
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i<vec.size(); ++i)
      std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
  }

};

#endif /* MY_CLASS_HPP */
```

main.cpp

```
#include "my_class.hpp"
#include <string>

int main() {

std::vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<std::string> v2{"Hello", "world", "!"};
std::vector<double> v3{2.5, 7.3, -5.1};

VectorPrinter vp1(v1);
VectorPrinter vp2(v2);
VectorPrinter vp3(v3);

return 0;

}
```

I get the following error message while trying to compile (I tried -std=c++11, -std=c++14, -std=c++17: no difference; no difference neither switching from g++ to clang):

```
./my_class.hpp:19:5: error: cannot refer to variable template 'vec' without a template argument list
```

Now: my goal is to circumvent defining VectorPrinter as a template class or, alternatively, avoid specifying the template argument in the case VectorPrinter cannot be non-template; so my problem reside within the scope of either variable template or template argument deduction.

This is just a test for my thesis project; what I need to achieve, at the end, is being able to define a template library for RNG and to encapsulate these classes in more complex ones which perform Direct Simulation Monte Carlo. So, at the end I would like something like:

```
template <class engineType>
class RngObject {
   // ...
};
```

```
class Ensemble {
   private:
      template<class engineType> RngObject<engineType> rng;
   // ...
};
```

It would be quite boring having to define each and every class that encapsulate a RNG as template; moreover, I am asked to avoid using dynamic time polymorphism, at leat at this stage.

I hope someone can provide me some useful suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you making a deep copy of the vector to print?

Comment: @MooingDuck it's just a test; i actually, in my project I would use reference to RNG objects, instead

Answer (score 3):

The error message says quite clearly what you have to do: Specify the template argument for `vec`.

```
  template<class value_type>
  VectorPrinter(const std::vector<value_type>& vec_)
  {
    // Using a reference here so we don't have to type all this again and again.
    auto& v = vec<value_type>;
    v = vec_;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
      std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
  }
```

You'll also have to provide the definition for your variable template:

```
template<class value_type>
std::vector<value_type> VectorPrinter::vec;
```

Together this should give you what you're asking for: https://godbolt.org/z/gVFvFw
(Whether this is a good design for your use case is a different question).

Comment: Don't get it - can you explain how this can compile at all? `template<class value_type> static std::vector<value_type> vec;` - there's one static member vec, but type changes with each constructor call???

Comment: Hm, one static member created for each instantiated constructor?

Comment: @Aconcagua Correct. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template.

Comment: @Aconcagua Honestly, I've never seen it used before either. But the cppreference page details exactly what has to happen here (and the clange error messages are quite clear too).

Comment: Suppose it is such rarely seen because of forcing you into (numerous) static variables. That might be useful to avoid polymorphism *if* one needs the static variables anyway - or needs to avoid PM for performance reaons. Otherwise, I consider true template classes superior. (But still +1 for good answer.)

Comment: @MaxLanghof thank you; it does compile, even if I still can't understand the syntax 'vec<value_type>' (I am probably still too ignorant about templates...)

Comment: @MichelePellegrino Variable templates are probably not the best to start with. I mean, I don't really get the reason why we have to provide the definition separately either. Function templates are a much better start for learning templates.

Answer (score 1):

I have certain doubts if you are on the right way; you get forced to use static members this way, but now all instances will compete for this single common member (well, only all those that use the same template type, of course). This could lead to race conditions among those objects with same template type, especially in a multi-threaded environment.

A true template class would allow to have non-static members, which might be safer and thus preferable.

If you opted for template variables just for not having to repeat the template arguments on object creation, then there's good news: Since C++17, you can let [deduce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) class template arguments from constructor. So if you *do* make your class a template:

```
template<class value_type>
class VectorPrinter { /* ... */ };
```

you still can define your objects without having to specify the template arguments:

```
VectorPrinter vp1(v1); // fine with above template, too - since C++17
```

but don't rely on static members.

If you wanted to place multiple `VectorPrinter`s (template version) of different types into a common container, though, then you'd need to introduce a common base class. So in such a scenario, you have the choice: No static variables (especially: no varying number of), but polymorphism, or the other way round. I have my clear personal preference (doesn't mean I'd refuse the other approach, if proved superior in a specific scenario), but you'll have to weigh up yourself...

Comment: yes, you are right: this is probably a bad idea, I may try the way of template argument deduction, even if I am not keen in relying too much on the new features of the C++17 standard